# How to define a structure and create instances of it in different javascripts files

Tags: javascript, html

**Updated Question:**

I have two files within the same project, one.js and two.js

one.js

```
var fruit = {
   name,
   color,
}
```

two.js

```
//Here i receive a json string with list of fruit objects
//For each object in the list create a new fruit object in javascript

var received_list = JSON.parse(response);

fruit_1 = new fruit();
fruit_1.name = received_list.fruit[0].name;
fruit_1.color = received_list.fruit[0].color;

fruit_2 = new fruit();
fruit_2.name = received_list.fruit[1].name;
fruit_2.color = received_list.fruit[1].color;
```

The syntax might be incorrect but i hope it clears out my question.

Here is my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="one.js"></script>
<script src="two.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
//some content
</body>
</html>
```

PS - I dont want to initialize apple and mango in one.js, I want them to be initialized in two.js.

Comment: Are `apple` and `mango` defined within `one.js`?

Comment: The code quoted doesn't match up with the error, you should either be getting a `SyntaxError` prior to the `ReferenceError` (on an older browser), or you should be getting a `ReferenceError` saying that `apple` is not defined (rather than `fruit`) (on a browser supporting ES2015's shorthand property syntax). Please put a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: Addressing your title: There's just one global namespace in in-browser JavaScript, so global variables defined by `one.js` are accessible by `two.js` (and vice-versa, if you handle the timing). So provided the code shown for `one.js` is at global scope, and `one.js` is completing without errors, `two.js` should be able to access `fruit`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a structure and create mutiple instances of it in different javascripts files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449975/how-to-define-a-structure-and-create-mutiple-instances-of-it-in-different-javasc)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the fruit object is invalid, a value for each field must be given.

```
var fruit = {
   apple: '',
   mango: ''
}
```

Edit:
Apparently, that syntax is valid (maybe es6) but apple and mango have to be defined before.

Comment: This doesn't explain the quoted error. On an older browser, you'd see a syntax error before the error quoted. On an up-to-date browser, the *syntax* is valid (as of ES2015 [aka ES6]), but they probably didn't mean to use it, and unless there were in-scope `apple` and `mango` variables, they'd be getting a different `ReferenceError` earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing your title:

> How to access a javascript variable from one js file in another js file

There's just one global namespace for JavaScript scripts loaded via the `script` tag<sup>1</sup>, so global variables defined by `one.js` are accessible by `two.js` (and vice-versa, if you handle the timing). So provided the code shown for `one.js` is at global scope, and `one.js` completes without errors, `two.js` will be able to access `fruit`.

> I am running this code on latest version of chrome and i get the following sequence of errors.
>
> `Uncaught ReferenceError: fruit is not defined`
>
> `Uncaught ReferenceError: apple is not defined`

With all due respect, from the code in the question you should be getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: apple is not defined                    at one.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'apple' of undefined     at two.js
```

(Order and details matter.)

That's because as of ES2015 (aka ES6), which Chrome has supported for several versions, this syntax:

```
var fruit = {
   apple,
   mango
}
```

...is the same as this:

```
var fruit = {
   apple: apple,
   mango: mango
}
```

...which is trying to create an object and initialize its `apple` and `mango` properties with the values of the variables `apple` and `mango`. But you don't have `apple` and `mango` variables, and so you get an error trying to access `apple` and the object isn't created at all.

> PS - I dont want to initialize apple and mango in one.js, I want them to be initialized in two.js.

Then just don't include them in `one.js` at all. A JavaScript object doesn't have to have its properties pre-declared, you can add new properties at any time (unless you intentionally use one of the ES5+ features to limit that).

So:

`one.js`:

```
var fruit = {};
```

`two.js`:

```
fruit.apple = "red";
```

The rest is fine (although unless you have a good reason for putting `script` tags in the `head`, put them in the `body`, at the very end, prior to the closing `</body>` tag).

---

<sup>1</sup> *"There's just one global namespace for JavaScript scripts loaded via the `script` tag"*

Two notes on that statement:

1. It's true, but soon it won't be the whole story. Sometime this year, browsers will start supporting JavaScript *modules*, which will be loaded via `<script type="module" ...>` tags. There's still a single shared global scope, but the code in modules isn't executed in that global scope, it's executed in its own module scope. So top-level variable declarations will no longer create global variables. (Which is a Good Thing™.) If/when you switch to using modules once they're supported, you'll use `import` instead of relying on globals (although it'll still be possible to create them if necessary).
2. Scripts loaded as web workers (so, not via `script` tags) each have their own global scope.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in one.js that causes `fruit` to not be initialized. Thus, you get a reference error in two.js when it tries to run. You can either initialize `apple` and `mango`:

```
var apple = {};
var mango = {};
var fruit = {
    apple,
    mango
};
```

or use a different object syntax:

```
var fruit = {
    apple: {},
    mango: {}
};
// var fruit = {} also works
```

Answer (score -1):

syntax bad:

```
var fruit = {
   apple,
   mango
}
```

try with this code:

```js
fruit.apple = "red";
console.log(fruit.apple);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
  var fruit = {
   "apple":'apple',
    "mango":'mango'
}
  </script>

</head>
<body>
//some content
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do not declare object keys already.

one.js

**var fruit = {};**

two.js

**fruit.apple='red';**

**fruit.mango='yellow;**

OR

one.js

**var fruit = {apple:''};**

Answer (score -2):

First you should validate your one.js object as said ...
Then by jQuery library you can do this easily .
First you should include one.js into two.js in this way:

```js
$.getScript("one.js", function(){

   fruit.apple = "red";

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```