# How to define a structure and create multiple instances of it in different JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files within the same project, one.js and two.js.

#### File `one.js`

```
var fruit = {
   name,
   color,
}
```

#### File `two.js`

```
// Here I receive a JSON string with list of fruit objects.
// For each object in the list create a new fruit object in JavaScript

var received_list = JSON.parse(response);

fruit_1 = new fruit();
fruit_1.name = received_list.fruit[0].name;
fruit_1.color = received_list.fruit[0].color;

fruit_2 = new fruit();
fruit_2.name = received_list.fruit[1].name;
fruit_2.color = received_list.fruit[1].color;
```

The syntax might be incorrect, but I hope it clears out my question.

Here is my index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="one.js"></script>
        <script src="two.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        // Some content
    </body>
</html>
```

PS - I don't want to initialize apple and mango in one.js; I want them to be initialized in two.js.

Comment: You can organize code in javascript using the Module pattern. You can read https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why would you want to create the instances like that, but there might be some implications.

You can use `Class` property of ES6;

**one.js**

```
class Fruit {
  constructor(name, color) {
    this.name = color;
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

**two.js**

```
var fruit_1 = new Fruit("apple", "red");
var fruit_2 = new Fruit(data_name, data_fruit);
```

Read On: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

---

Also really advise you to use modules and es6 preset instead including javascript files one by one to your HTML file.

See: https://babeljs.io/